# Dynamic allocation failing to scan number

Tags: c, dynamic, allocation, ansi-c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main(){
    int *ptr,r,c,i,j,min;
    printf("Give me the size of rows and columns\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&r,&c);
    int mini[r];
    ptr=(int*)malloc(r*c*sizeof(int));
    if(ptr== NULL){
        printf("Memory not allocated");
    }
    else{

        for(i=0;i<r;i++){
            for(j=0;j<c;j++){
            printf("Give me the value ");

            scanf("%d",&ptr+(i*c+j));
            }
        }

        for(i=0;i<r;i++){
            min=*(ptr+i*c); 
            for(j=0;j<c;j++){
                if (*(ptr+i*c)<min){
                    min = *(ptr+i*c);
                }
                mini[i]=min;
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<r;i++){
            printf("%d",mini[i]);

        }
        free(ptr);

    }
}
```

It gets the row and column (r and c ) values without a problem but it crashes as soon as i get to the point of scaning the allocated memory elements. For example if i set `r==3` and `c==4` then it gets to asking the 10th element of the 12 and then it crashes saying that filename.exe has stopped working.

From my experience I think this has something to do with the `scanf()` function. I also tried without the & in the `scanf`, `scanf("%d",ptr +(i*c +j))` but then it crashes as soon as it gets to read the first element.

In another much simpler program I wrote to check it the latter scenario of `scanf()` does not present any problems and the program runs as it was supposed to.

Comment: `if(ptr= NULL){` it's an assignment, not comparison, so I guess you have some typos there as the code you're talking about couldn't execute otherwise.. Please correct them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong

```
scanf("%d",&ptr+(i*c+j));
```

it should be

```
scanf("%d", &(*(ptr + i*c + j)));
```

or since, the `ptr` points to the addres, you should not dereference the pointer and then pass the address, just

```
scanf("%d", ptr + i*c + j);
```

in your code you are passing the address of the pointer `ptr` incremented by `i * c + j`, which is presumably an invalid address, and hence the segmentation fault occur.

Also, it's not the first time I see a `scanf()` where the return value is ignored, if you type a string then a crash will occur.

You should ensure that an integer was read with

```
if (scanf("%d", &(*(ptr + i * c + j))) == 1)
```

if the condition is false, then no value was read, for example if you type text instead of numbers.

Comment: Isn't this a perfect opportunity to show the OP how to *correctly* index arrays?

Comment: well `&(*(...))` surely has some humor!

Comment: It's just to let him know that the syntax he tried is not correct, though there is a correct way of writing a similar syntax, it's not the best way, sure, but it's not wrong.

Comment: @Jongware i didn't quite get what you said. Iharob thanks for the help

Comment: You can always add "a better way to index is ..." And I see no reason for that downvote!

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d",&ptr+(i*c+j));
```

is hazardous!

`&ptr*` contains the address to pointer to the first element of `ptr`, not the address of the first element!

What you need is simply `ptr + (i*c +j)`, or `&(ptr[i*c+j])`.

Comment: thank you very much that was the mistake, it runs smoothly now :)

Answer (score 0):

In the second `scanf()` `"%d"` expects format of type `int*`  i.e pointer , but i see that you are passing the address of pointer as `&ptr+(i*c+j)` which is `int**`